# How to specify file path that works in Windows?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to figure out how to create a path name so that I can copy files into a certain directory on Windows.  The code below is giving me an error that the `volume label syntax is incorrect`.

How do I fix this?

```
def copytree(src, dst):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
    
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            #destDir = os.path.join(dst, item)
            os.mkdir(d)
            copytree(s, d)
        else:
            filename, extn = os.path.splitext(item)
            print ("file " + filename + " extn  " + extn)
            if (extn != ".py" and extn != ".png"):
                continue
                
            shutil.copy(s, d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    copyToBlenderAddons = False

    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        if arg == "-b":
            copyToBlenderAddons = True

    blenderHome = None
    platSys = platform.system()
    if platSys == 'Windows':
        blenderHome = '"%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.91\\"'
    elif platSys == 'Linux':
        blenderHome = "$HOME/.config/blender/2.91/"
    elif platSys == 'MacOS':
        blenderHome = "/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.91/"


    if copyToBlenderAddons: 
        path = blenderHome + "scripts/addons"
        print("Copying to blender addons: " + path)
        copytree("build", path);
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the windows path to be between simple quotes AND double quotes ?

Comment: %USERPROFILE% is not a correct syntax for Window paths. You need to read the environment variable at first and then add to the read content the rest of the path. b.t.w. there is a environment variable %APPDATA% which containts the Roaming path.

Comment: The path has a space in it, so I thought the extra quotes would be necessary.

Comment: ```os.getenv('APPDATA')``` did the trick.